# How to log all errors in angular application into database using web API

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to handle all errors in my angular application and log each errors into database. Can anyone explain how to log errors by calling web API with an example. Note that I am using Angular 10

Comment: use Interseptors

Comment: Ok.  I will try in that way

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.